# Registering one Backbone model with multiple views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is an architecture question. Let's say I have one model and N views may (or may not) be bound to it. How do I make changes in this model so all views change? I suspect there must be some design pattern for this. I've thought of having my backbone model have an array of views and have a function that simply goes through said array and triggers the name of the view as an event.

Is that a way to do this? What pattern could I use? How should I architect something like this?

Comment: Bind your views to the relevant events on the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should not be aware of the views presenting it, to maintain the MVC separation of concerns. Read the docs on [events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events). You can have your views listen to the `change` event and then update themselves accordingly.

The [documentation of Views](http://backbonejs.org/#View) has a good example of this:

```
var DocumentRow = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: "li",

  className: "document-row",

  events: {
    "click .icon":          "open",
    "click .button.edit":   "openEditDialog",
    "click .button.delete": "destroy"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  }

  render: function() {
    ...
  }

});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thank Jeremy Ashkenas for the awesomeness that is Backbone!